# Between Operator - Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing a raw query to fetch records between two dates.

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` 
WHERE '01-08-2017 11:00' 
BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date` AND `who`='vf00'
```

This query is returning results as below

```
start_date : 01-05-2017 10:30
end_date: 03-05-2017 10:00
```

It should not return any result since **01-08-2017 11:00** is not in between any range.

Comment: your query is invalid. I doubt you have a column named `01-08-2017 11:00`.

Comment: 01-08-2017 is actually between 01-05-2017 and 03-05-2017.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: How come its between ? 08 is August month & 05 is May?

Comment: @Fred-ii- according to BETWEEN documentation you can either add column name or expression
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Comment: @Zack Thanks. I'll get back to you on that by running a few tests of my own.

Comment: @Zack I'm curious though. Is this more of a "why/behaviour" type of question? MySQL relies on `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` as a datetime method, your `01-08-2017 11:00` won't work. MySQL's manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between states that you may have to CAST those or use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: @Fred-ii-, solved by casting & datetime method YMD. Thanks

Comment: Right on @Zack and you're welcome.